# Xamarin.Forms, cannot reach class from platform specific projects

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

At first I have a Multi-platform Project where I created a Class which transfers Data and my problem is that as example if I click a Button a method in this class should be called but I cannot reach the method.

This is my project structure:
[image]

The red part is where the Data Handler is located
the green part from where I get the clicked event and call the method.

I'll hope someone can help me with this problem!

Comment: you cannot call a method in the platform code from the shared code - shared code does not have a reference to the platform code.  To get around this you need to use DI - see https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/dependency-service/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jason mentioned in comment, you can not reach code from platform specific **just like that**, because you are not referencing platform specific projects, and there is something called `DependencyService` (which Jason also mentioned) and that will help you to solve this "issue" that you have.

This is how you can use `DependencyService`, inside your shared code project, create one interface in my case that will be:

```
public interface IDataHandler
{
    string GetSomeStringValue();
}
```

Go to your iOS or other platform specific project and create new class DataHandler.cs (which you already have). And it should implement this interface that we created. Something like this:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(DataHandler))]
namespace provisioning.ios
{
    public class DataHandler: IDataHandler
    {

        public DataHandler()
        {
        }

        public string GetSomeStringValue()
        {
            return "Some string value or whatever";
        }
    }
}
```

After that when you want to reach this method you will use DepedencyService inside of your shared code project like this:

```
private void SomeMethod()
{
    string fromSpecificProject = DependencyService.Get<IDataHandler>().GetSomeStringValue();
}
```

If you want or need you can use this to pass some values to platform specific project and to return the data like I did it this mini example.

> Note that implementations must be provided for each platform project
>   in your solution. Platform projects without implementations will fail
>   at runtime!

Strongly recommend you to take a look at official docs [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction/).

Also I made this mini blogpost about usage of Dependency Service in Xamarin.Forms apps you can find it [here](https://almirvuk.blogspot.ba/2017/09/xamarinforms-dependencyservice.html).